# UIAppearance and Rounded Borders in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, uiappearance

So I'm fairly new to the whole UIAppearance approach to doing things, and doing it with swift. Hurray for not a ton of documentation out there.

I'm trying to set my border radius through UIAppearance with something along the lines of:

```
CircleButton.appearance.roundBorderRadius = 9
```

My CircleButton class implementation:

```
public class CircleButton : UIButton{
     @nonobjc var roundBorderRadius: CGFloat? {
        get { return self.layer.cornerRadius }
        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue!
        }
    }
}
```

And I hook everything up in Storyboard to a ViewController that contains a CircleButton.  No Compilation or Build errors.

However, at runtime I'm getting a:

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on:

```
CircleButton.appearance.roundBorderRadius = 9
```

Any advice?

Comment: You can try a non-`UIAppearance`-based approach to styling to work with properties of nested objects directly. One such micro-framework with composable and reusable styles is [StyleSheet](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `@nonobjc` and add `dynamic`, then change the type from `CGFloat?` to `CGFloat` and remove the `!` after `newValue` in the setter, like so:

```
public class CircleButton: UIButton {

    dynamic var roundBorderRadius: CGFloat {
        get { 
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }

        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any explenation about the actual **why** it crashes thought? From what I guess, the UIAppearance only works with **ObjC** objects, which means you can't use Swift object to connect to UIAppearance?